# Write TOML file to deserialize into enum in a struct

Tags: rust, enums, serde, toml

If I have a enum with a struct value, what is the correct TOML format to represent it?

Suppose I have

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Clone)]
pub enum AOrB
{
    A,
    B {
      b1: String,
      b2: String
    },
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct Config
{
    pub z: String,
    pub a_or_b: AOrB
}
```

And I try to deserialize a string into a `Config`,

```
fn main()
{
    // What should this be?
    let s = r#"
z = "zzz"

[a_or_b.B]
b1 = "bbb"
b2 = "bbbb"
"#;
    let c: Config = toml::from_str(s).unwrap();
}
```

I get error: `enum table must contain exactly one table", key: ["a_or_b"]`. I tried some different forms of `s` but none worked. What's the correct way of writing `s`?

(I need b1 and b2 to be at different lines.)

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6d2101007d0b09f5553859dfa74e1abb)

---

UPDATE: Seems like if I write it inline, it's fine:

```
z = "zzz"
a_or_b = { B = { b1 = "bbb", b2 = "bbbb" } }
```

However I do need the fields to be at separate lines, because in my real case there are more of them and their values are long...

Comment: After some initial investigation, it seems like a bug in the `toml` crate. Let me investigate further. You also don't seem to be the first one to stumble across it: https://github.com/toml-rs/toml-rs/issues/390

Comment: It seems a pull request is already open: https://github.com/toml-rs/toml/pull/358

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the `toml` crate. A fix [already exists and should get merged at some point](https://github.com/toml-rs/toml/pull/358), but for now you might have to work around it by using the branch with the fix directly:

*Cargo.toml*

```ini
[dependencies]
toml = { git = "https://github.com/HarveyHunt/toml", branch = "dotted-table-parsing-toml" }
```

Then, your code simply works:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub enum AOrB {
    A,
    B { b1: String, b2: String },
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Config {
    pub z: String,
    pub a_or_b: AOrB,
}

fn main() {
    // What should this be?
    let s = r#"
z = "zzz"

[a_or_b.B]
b1 = "bbb"
b2 = "bbbb"
"#;
    let c: Config = toml::from_str(s).unwrap();

    println!("{:#?}", c);
}
```

```
Config {
    z: "zzz",
    a_or_b: B {
        b1: "bbb",
        b2: "bbbb",
    },
}
```

Comment: I think it doesn't support serialization from it. But they do have an example file showing deserialization enums, including enums with struct in an array. https://github.com/toml-rs/toml/blob/main/crates/toml/examples/enum_external.rs.

I just don't know how to write that for enum in a struct...

Comment: @MetroWind Updated the answer, first one was nonesense indeed :)